# Pointwise convergence of sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \sin(\frac{x}{n})$ where $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise.

I've tried graphing a few of the functions on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%2Fn%29+for+n+%3D+1+to+5) but it's not obvious what they should converge to, apart from the fact that we need $f(0) = 0$. How do I work out $f$?

Comment: Fix $x$. Then $x/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $\sin t$ is continuous at $t=0$, $\sin(x/n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $x$, so $f_n\to 0$ pointwise.

Comment: Fill in the definition of pointwise convergence for this example and it will be clear based on continuity of $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For fixed $x$, what is $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{x}{n}$?